# Pillow new RGB screen not generating

Tags: python-imaging-library

I built a test program using import PIL.imagedraw etc etc and was able to use the draw.line command to draw various lines. All good. In a new program I added new code which built a matrix list of x/y/z points (and cosine/sine expressions with math.lib), an input command for some variables, and then the draw.line command as in the previous code, but now the RGB window is not showing at all. The program doesn’t end and gives no errors. (Pythonista on iOS iPad Pro)

The test program, a noob attempt at perspective projection (which works as expected):

```
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw,PIL.Image as Image, PIL.ImageShow as ImageShow
im = Image.new("RGB", (1200,800))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

GL_z = 0
PP_y = 0
SP_x = 300

SP_y = -400

SP_z = 600

org=600

answer=0

width=100

depth=500

height=500

SP_z1=SP_z+height

px_1 = org

py_1 = org

px_2 = org+90

py_2 = 50 + org

px_3 = -160 + org

py_3 = 550 + org

px_4 = -250 + org

py_4 = 500+org

while answer==0:

SP_z1=SP_z-height

px1_1 = ((px_1 - SP_x)/(py_1 - SP_y))*(py_1 - PP_y)
px1_2 = ((px_2 - SP_x)/(py_2 - SP_y))*(py_2 - PP_y)
px1_3 = ((px_3 - SP_x)/(py_3 - SP_y))*(py_3 - PP_y)
px1_4 = ((px_4 - SP_x)/(py_4 - SP_y))*(py_4 - PP_y)

py1_1 = ((SP_z-GL_z)/(py_1-SP_y))*(py_1-PP_y)
py1_2 = ((SP_z-GL_z)/(py_2-SP_y))*(py_2-PP_y)
py1_3 = ((SP_z-GL_z)/(py_3-SP_y))*(py_3-PP_y)
py1_4 = ((SP_z-GL_z)/(py_4-SP_y))*(py_4-PP_y)

py1_5 = ((SP_z1-GL_z)/(py_1-SP_y))*(py_1-PP_y)
py1_6 = ((SP_z1-GL_z)/(py_2-SP_y))*(py_2-PP_y)
py1_7 = ((SP_z1-GL_z)/(py_3-SP_y))*(py_3-PP_y)
py1_8 = ((SP_z1-GL_z)/(py_4-SP_y))*(py_4-PP_y)

px1_1old = px1_1
px1_2old = px1_2 
px1_3old = px1_3
px1_4old = px1_4

py1_1old = py1_1
py1_2old = py1_2
py1_3old = py1_3
py1_4old = py1_4

py1_5old = py1_5
py1_6old = py1_6
py1_7old = py1_7
py1_8old = py1_8

SP_yold = SP_y



draw.line((0,SP_y,1200,SP_y),fill=(255,255,255))

draw.line((px1_1,py1_1,px1_2,py1_2),fill=(0,0,255))
draw.line((px1_2,py1_2,px1_3,py1_3),fill=(0,255,0))
draw.line((px1_3,py1_3,px1_4,py1_4),fill=(255,255,255))
draw.line((px1_4,py1_4,px1_1,py1_1),fill=(100,255,0))

draw.line((px1_1,py1_1,px1_1,py1_5),fill=(255,255,255))
draw.line((px1_1,py1_5,px1_2,py1_6),fill=(255,255,255))
draw.line((px1_2,py1_6,px1_3,py1_7),fill=(255,255,255))
draw.line((px1_3,py1_7,px1_4,py1_8),fill=(255,255,255))
draw.line((px1_4,py1_8,px1_4,py1_4),fill=(150,150,0))



#draw.line((px1_1,py1_1,px1_2,py1_2),fill=(255,255,255))
#draw.line((px1_2,py1_2,px1_3,py1_3),fill=(255,255,255))
#draw.line((px1_3,py1_3,px1_4,py1_4),fill=(255,255,255))
#draw.line((px1_4,py1_4,px1_1,py1_1),fill=(255,255,255))

im.show()

move = input("''")

if move == "w":
    SP_y += 50
if move == "s":
    SP_x -= 50
if move == "z":
    SP_y -= 50
if move == "a":
    SP_x += 50  
if move == "-":
    SP_z -= 50      
if move == "=":
    SP_z += 50          
    
    
draw.line((0,SP_yold,1200,SP_yold),fill=(0,0,0))    
    
draw.line((px1_1old,py1_1old,px1_2old,py1_2old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_2old,py1_2old,px1_3old,py1_3old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_3old,py1_3old,px1_4old,py1_4old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_4old,py1_4old,px1_1old,py1_1old),fill=(0,0,0))

draw.line((px1_1old,py1_1old,px1_1old,py1_5old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_1old,py1_5old,px1_2old,py1_6old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_2old,py1_6old,px1_3old,py1_7old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_3old,py1_7old,px1_4old,py1_8old),fill=(0,0,0))
draw.line((px1_4old,py1_8old,px1_4old,py1_4old),fill=(0,0,0))
```

And this is the code that refuses to draw anything:

```
import math

import decimal 
decimal.getcontext().prec = 6

import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw,PIL.Image as Image, PIL.ImageShow as ImageShow 
 im = Image.new("RGB", (1200,800))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

PP_y = 0
SP_x = 300
SP_y = -400
SP_z = 600
org=600
answer=0


dims=[]
for i in range (1, 5):
    dim = int(input())
    dims.append(dim)

dims[3] = (dims[3]*math.pi)/180


obj1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18],[19,20,21],[22,23,24]]

y1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y2 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
y3 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
z1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
ymod = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
xmod = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

obj1[0]=[0,0,0]

obj1[1]=[dims[0] * math.cos(dims[3]),dims[0] * math.sin(dims[3]),0]

obj1[2]=[obj1[1][0] - (dims[1] * math.sin(dims[3])),obj1[1][1] + (dims[1] * math.cos(dims[3])),0]

obj1[3]=[dims[1] * math.sin(dims[3]),dims[1] * math.cos(dims[3]),0]

obj1[4]=[0,0,dims[2]]

obj1[5]=[dims[0] * math.cos(dims[3]),dims[0] * math.sin(dims[3]),dims[2]]

obj1[6]=[obj1[1][0] - (dims[1] * math.sin(dims[3])),obj1[1][1] + (dims[1] * math.cos(dims[3])),dims[2]]

 obj1[7]=[dims[1] * math.sin(dims[3]),dims[1] * math.cos(dims[3]),dims[2]]

for i in range (0,7):
    y1[i]=obj1[i][1]-PP_y
    y2[i]=obj1[i][1]-SP_y
    y3[i]=y1[i]/y2[i]
    x1[i]=obj1[i][0]-SP_y
    z1[i]=obj1[i][2]-SP_z
    obj1[i][0]=obj1[i][0] - (x1[i] * y3[i])
    obj1[i][2]=obj1[i][2] - (z1[i] * y3[i])

#print(dims)
#print(obj1)
#print(y1,y2,y3,x1,z1,xmod,ymod)


while (True):

    draw.line((obj1[0][0],obj1[0][2],obj1[1][0],obj1[1][2]),fill=(255,255,255))
```

Comment: `answer = 0` followed by `while answer==0` ?

Comment: Yeah I know, try not to look… this is not the problem but a coding issue which I will learn properly…

Answer (score 0):

Ah found the error, left out im.show(). Pretty fundamental…

reference
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html